# Symfony Dependency Injection XML to YAML

Tags: symfony

How i can define service look like this in YAML pattern?

XML:

```
<service id="my_service" class="MyClass">
   <!-- XML FORMAT NO NEED TO DEFINE THIS ARGUMENT IN OTHER SERVICE -->
    <argument type="service">
        <service class="OtherFacotryServiceClass" factory-service="other_facoty_service" factory-method="get">
            <argument>other_service_param</argument>
        </service>
    </argument>
</service>
```

This will output in PHP: (in a container dump)

```
protected function getMYServiceService()
{
    return $this->services['my_service'] = new \MyClass($this->get('other_facoty_service')->get('other_service_param'));
}
```

**EDITED: Full (long) yaml definition.**

```
services:
    an_other_service:
        public: false
        class: OtherFacotryServiceClass
        factory_service: other_facoty_service
        factory_method: get
        arguments: [other_service_param]

    my_service:
        class: MyClass
        arguments: [@an_other_service]
```

**How i can define similar XML like:**

```
services:
    # THIS'S WRONG FORMAT!!
    my_service:
        class: MyClass
        arguments:
            -
                class: OtherFacotryServiceClass
                factory_service: other_facoty_service
                factory_method: get
                arguments: [other_service_param]
```

Comment: It's not possible as in yaml it's hard to make a distinction between a child service definition and an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your services.yml

```
services:
  my_service_factory:
    class: OtherFactoryServiceClass

  my_service:
    class: MyClass
    factory_service: my_service_factory
    factory_method: get
    arguments: [other_service_param] # arguments are injected in "OtherFactoryServiceClass::get"
```

[Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html)

Comment: @ツLiverbool provide more info. "Expected PHP: (in container dump)" is not clear enough.

Comment: Can we combine into one definition?

Comment: As far as I know, no.